# preg_match string

Tags: php, preg-match

Can someone explain me the meaning of this pattern.

`preg_match(/'^(d{1,2}([a-z]+))(?:s*)S (?=200[0-9])/','21st March 2006','$matches);`

So correct me if I'm wrong:

```
    ^        = beginning of the line   
    d{1,2}   = digit with minimum 1 and maximum 2 digits  
    ([a-z]+) = one or more letters from a-z
    (?:s*)S  = no idea...  
    (?=      = no idea...
    200[0-9] = a number, starting with 200 and ending with a number (0-9)
```

Can someone complete this list?

Comment: Aren't we missing backslashes before d, s, S and so on?

Comment: I got your point, but no. The book does'nt mention backslashes...

Comment: Then do not trust the book ;)

Comment: Haha, yet, it's the PHP Zend Practice Guide. So you would think they know what they are talking about...

Comment: ;) They surely present character classes as \x where x belongs to d,s, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice diagram courtesy of [strfriend](http://www.strfriend.com/vis?re=%5E%28d%7B1%2C2%7D%28%5Ba%2Dz%5D%2B%29%29%28%3F%3As%2A%29S%20%28%3F%3D200%5B0%2D9%5D%29):

[image: ^(d{1,2}([a-z]+))(?:s*)S (?=200[0-9])]

But I think you probably meant `^(\d{1,2}([a-z]+))(?:\s*)\S (?=200[0-9])` with the backslashes, which gives [this diagram](http://www.strfriend.com/vis?re=%5E%28%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%28%5Ba%2Dz%5D%2B%29%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2A%29%5CS%20%28%3F%3D200%5B0%2D9%5D%29):

[image: ^(\d{1,2}([a-z]+))(?:\s*)\S (?=200[0-9])]

That is, this regexp matches the beginning of the string, followed by one or two digits, one or more lowercase letters, zero or more whitespace characters, one non-whitespace character and a space.  Also, all this has to be followed by a number between 2000 and 2009, although that number is not actually matched by the regexp — it's only a look-ahead assertion.  Also, the leading digits and letters are captures into `$matches[1]`, and just the letters into `$matches[2]`.

For more information on PHP's PCRE regexp syntax, see http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php

Comment: No backslashes mentionned in the exercise. But your answer and link was very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[regular-exressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) is very helpful resource.

`/'^(d{1,2}([a-z]+))(?:s*)S (?=200[0-9])/`

`(?:regex)` are non-capturing parentheses; They aren't very useful in your example, but could be used to expres things like `(?:bar)+`, to mean 1 or more `bar`s

`(?=regex)` does a positive lookahead, but matches the position not the contents. So `(?=200[0-9])` in your example makes the regex match only dates in the previous decade, **without** matching the year itself.